# Why do amsmath and \char interact in this way?

Tags: amsmath

I discovered this when trying to redefine \char to denote the characteristic of a field and got a weird error message. Below is a minimal example to demonstrate the weird thing that happened.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\char}{\stepcounter{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{test}

test$1 + 1 = 2$test$2 + 2 = 4$test

\section{test}

test$1 + 1 = 2$test$2 + 2 = 4$test

\section{test}

\end{document}
```

If you typeset this, you will get sections numbered 1, 3, and 4. Experimenting with this, I have determined that the first inline math, display math, or align environment of a document causes \char to be called once, and from then on, nothing else seems to be able to make it be called again. This ONLY happens if the amsmath package is loaded. What in the world is going on? Is there any way for me to redefine \char without causing weird issues?

Comment: Don't redefine `\char`, it's a TeX primitive!

Comment: @JosephWright Is there a possibility of messing anything up "under the hood" if I redefine a LaTeX macro, or does this only happen with TeX primitives? Is there a website that lists TeX primitives?

Comment: "Is there a possibility of messing anything up "under the hood" if I redefine a LaTeX macro, "  it is not just a possibility, it is a certainty. tex is a macro expansion language not a compiled language, if you change, say `\mbox` you change every command that directly or indirectly uses that command. That is why latex has `\newcommand` so you do not accidentally redefine anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Is it possible to safely redefine `\char`? Not without ***a lot*** of work that would prove useless.

Never do `\renewcommand` on a command you don't know about. For your command do

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Char}{char}
```

and use `\Char`. Or maybe `\fldchar`, choose the name you deem best, but ***not*** `\char`.

#### Extended answer

The specific error is due to the fact that `amsmath` uses `\char` in its `\resetMathstrut@` macro, which is executed every time a math formula first appears after a font size change.

```
\def\resetMathstrut@{%
  \begingroup
  \setbox\z@\hbox{%
    \mathchardef\@tempa\mathcode`\(\relax
    \def\@tempb##1"##2##3{\the\textfont"##3\char"}%
    \expandafter\@tempb\meaning\@tempa \relax
  }%
 \edef\@tempa{%
     \ht\Mathstrutbox@\the\ht\z@\relax
     \dp\Mathstrutbox@\the\dp\z@\relax}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\@tempa
}
```

It's not really necessary to describe what this macro does, apart from telling that it sets up a math strut to be used in the alignment environments.

With your code, this macro is executed only once, but if you add a formula in the argument to `\section` you'll see that it's executed once more.

Is there a way to safely redefine `\char`? Yes, there is: make your own copy of the whole LaTeX tree, add `\let\primitivechar\char` at the beginning of (the copy of) `latex.ltx`; then replace every other occurrence of `\char` in the whole tree with `\primitivechar`. Then recompile the formats. You never know which package might use `\char`.

A run of `ack` (or `grep`) tells that `\char` appears 8682 times in a total of 960 files:

```bash
> ack -ch '\\char[^a-z]' /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/
8682
> ack -cl '\\char' /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ | wc -l
960
```

Consider, though, that nobody other than you would be able to run LaTeX on your document. So the answer to your question is

***Yes, but for all practical purposes, no.***

Some background. One of the original aims of LaTeX3 was to *undefine* every primitive, replacing them with aliases. However, the team realized that this is impractical, because it would mean that essentially no current package could be used with the new version and there are thousands of them!

Why didn't the original LaTeX do this step? For various reasons, here are the main ones:

1. at the time LaTeX was written, plain TeX was the only format available and LaTeX borrowed several plain constructs;
2. transition from plain to LaTeX would be easier, allowing to reuse code;
3. computer memory was scarce; ***really*** scarce.

When LaTeX2e was released, it might have been an occasion for carrying on the project of aliasing every primitive and replacing them with aliases, because packages were not so many. But LaTeX would not run on basically any machine, because every alias takes memory space. Nowadays such memory considerations aren't an issue, but packages count in the thousands.

In some cases it's possible to redefine a primitive, but only in order to change a bit its behavior: LaTeX does it with `\input`, for instance, but the redefined `\input` will always eventually call the alias to the primitive.

Answer (score 9):

`\char` is the TeX primitive to access a character by number, so redefining that will break all kinds of latex constructs, not just `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\char}{\stepcounter{section}}


\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,0){\circle{5}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

LaTeX can not select a circle of the right size.

Always use `\newcommand` to avoid accidental redefinitons. Only use `\renewcommand` when you wish to change the behaviour of all uses of an existing command.